# How to add edit button to UINavigationBar after push on UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I want to add the edit button of a table view to the navigation bar of a navigation controller after pushing this new table view on the navigation controller.  When I do that, the edit button doesn't appear (I suspect the 'Back' button obscures it), and when I go back up the hierarchy, there it is, but now I have two of them (Edit Edit).  My source code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let items:UITableViewController = ItemsController()
  myNavigationController.pushViewController(items, animated:true)
  myNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem!.leftBarButtonItems! += [ items.editButtonItem() ]
}
```

EDIT

If I comment out the last line above, and insert the following line before push, the Edit button appears on the left, but there is now no Back button:

```
items.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = items.editButtonItem()
```

SOLUTION

The solution I am using in viewDidLoad() of ItemsController():

```
    var items = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
    if items == nil {
        items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    }
    items! += [ editButtonItem() ]
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the left and right bar buttons of a `UINavigationItem` can be represented as a single `barButtonItem` or an array of `barButtonItems`. You need to access and set the latter (which adds a button instead of just replacing the `Back` button). To do this within the same viewController, use this code:

```
if var leftBarButtonItems = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems{
            leftBarButtonItems.append(self.editButtonItem())
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftBarButtonItems
        }
```

However, if at all possible I would use the above code to put the `Edit` button on the right side, as that is where it is expected.

Comment: your code works when placed inside the viewDidLoad() method of the UIViewController that is pushed onto the UINavigationController